# Changing membership prices and deciding to whom they should apply

Tags: civimember, renewals

Prices need to increase at end of Financial Year.

So if someone's end date is eg EOFY -1, then they should pay existing price, even if they renew after their End Date (ie any time till end of Grace period)

if someone's end date is eg EOFY +1, then they should pay new price, even if they renew before the EOFY date.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Approach we are considering is CiviDiscount which lets us set a discount to apply to specified contacts (eg those in a Group whose End Date is before EOFY) and to apply automatically to a Membership

Hence

- we increase the price of memberships on day X (well before the EOFY)
- we set up the 'group' that the Discount applies to as a group for everyone whose End Date is before EOFY
  so the outcome should be
- folk in that Group see the discounted rate
- those with renewal dates after EOFY see the new rate regardless of when they renew